# Launcher Icons Collapse

Tags: 12.04, unity, launcher

My launcher's icons collapse when I run out of space. How do I turn this off?

Comment: That's by design. I don't think it can be changed. The collapsed icons will show themselves as you move your mouse up and down over the launcher, just like you would do with your finger on touch.

Comment: That's a shame. I find it quite annoying, as the launcher springs back to showing the Dash button at the top, and sometimes I'm working on programs in the bottom section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is by design. As far as I know, there is no way to change it.

The collapsed icons will show themselves as you move your mouse up and down over the launcher, just like you would do with your finger on a touchscreen.

You can re-arrange the order of the icons by clicking the icon and holding it for a second, dragging it to the right towards the desktop, and then dropping it where you want it higher up. The new order will be stay the same in future sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution: this isn't enabled in Ubuntu 2D. I don't know if using 2D causes any other problems / disadvantages, other than losing the "Aero Snap" feature.

To change from Ubuntu to Ubuntu 2D, at the login screen, click on the Ubuntu logo, and then chose Ubuntu 2D. If you then do a non-forced shut-down, then it will save this preference.

---

This is no longer avaliable for 14.04+.